# Inheriting a default template value

Tags: c++, templates

I have multiple aliases for a class and would like those aliases to inherit the base class' default template argument. Here is a simple example of syntactically what I'm trying to achieve:

```
template<int f = 5>
class A {}; 

template<int T/*= 5*/>
using Test = A<T>;

int main()
{
    A<> foo;
    Test<> foo2; // error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1)
}
```

Or do I have to resort to making the default value an explicitly accessible value?

```
static const int DefaultVal = 5;

template<int f = DefaultVal>
class A {}; 

template<int T= DefaultVal>
using Test = A<T>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "inherit" default value.

Another possibility is using variadic template:

```
template <int ... Ts>
using Test = A<Ts...>;
```

which allows `Test<>` as `A<>` so `A<5>`.

But it "lies" with invalid `Test<1, 2, 3, 4>`.